# Editing 'Password Reset' E-mail

Tags: filters, login, email, password

I'm trying to customize the e-mail that you receive from WordPress when you reset your password. Right now it's a WordPress e-mail but I'd like to brand it with our company's logo and custom information (but of course keep the reset password link).

I've been digging around the wp-login.php page but haven't tracked down where that is controlled. I'm well-versed in the PHP mail function (which I'm assuming is called here) so I can edit it if I find the code. Does anyone know where that code is? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WordPress uses custom `wp_mail` function, so you won't find it, if you'll search for `mail`.

Just take a look at line 248 of `wp-login.php` file: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.5/wp-login.php#L248

You should find `retrieve_password_message` filter call there. This is the filter that returns the content of reset password message.

You should also check the implementation of `wp_mail` function, because you will have to add headers to your mail (you want to send it as html and not as plain text, I guess). You can use `wp_mail_content_type` filter to change it.